# The anchor tag not working as should

Tags: php, html

the anchor tag not working, is there a syntax error?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.location.href='/user/<?php echo $user->uid; ?>/edit#shops'" >επιλέξτε εδώ</button>
```

> URL from firebug translates to: http://www.website.com/user/1/edit#shops

Comment: what are you expecting and what is happening ? and that is not `anchor` tag.

Comment: What's your question ?

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using `button` use `a` tag

```
 <a href="/user/<?php echo $user->uid; ?>/edit#shops">επιλέξτε εδώ</a>
```

Comment: I hate to be bearer of bad news here, but I'm seriously doubting you'll see a green tick here. OP's track record isn't very good. Oh well, you got +3 out of this ;-)